# Add type to enqueued script inside plugin

Tags: plugins, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

So I don't know if this is possible, but I have a question - We are integrating OneTrust and one of the requirements was to change `<script type='text/javascript'>` to `<script type='text/plain`>.

Inside one of the plugins that we have installed on WordPress, they have their file enqueued:

```php
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'juicerembed',
    '//assets.juicer.io/embed-no-jquery.js',
    array('jquery'),
    false,
    false
  );
```

When the script is loaded, it loads it with no type which defaults to `<script src='//assets.juicer.io/embed-no-jquery.js?ver=5.8.1' id='juicerembed-js'></script>`.

Is there a way to hook or filter into a plugins enqueued scripts and add a type? Adding it inside the plugin directly will just get overwritten on next updates.

1. Can you hook/filter possible?
2. Do you deregister the script and then reregister?

All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There's a filter: [`script_loader_tag`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/script_loader_tag/).

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wpse397773_change_script_tags', 10, 3 );
function wpse397773_change_script_tags( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    $tag = '<script type="text/plain" src="' . $src . '" id="' . $handle . '-js"></script>';
    return $tag;
}
```

This should change *all* the `<script>` tags in the page (assuming they're properly enqueued) to `<script type="text/plain">`.

**Update:** To *only* change the `<script>` tag for the `juicerembed` script, you can do this:

```
add_filter( 'script_loader_tag', 'wpse397773_change_script_tags', 10, 3 );
function wpse397773_change_script_tags( $tag, $handle, $src ) {
    if ( 'juicerembed' == $handle ) {
        $tag = '<script type="text/plain" src="' . $src . '" id="' . $handle . '-js"></script>';
    }
    return $tag;
}
```

I haven't tested this at all, but hopefully it'll be a starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks so much @Pat! Is it possible to alter just one single script tag with that filter so I don't change them all? I've got them all updated except the one above, so if something is off, I'd like the above to just be filtered.

Comment: Yeah, you can check to see if the `$handle` matches the script's handle. I've updated my answer with a code snippet to check for the `juicerembed` handle you've got in your original question.